# CodIgniter - Setup db(create tables etc) for existing project

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a fully completed existing codeigniter project with me.
I created a mysql db locally and changed dbnames in database.php.

Now, how to setup this db by creating tables etc as per the code.

I thought db/tables would be automatically created but when I opened page it said 'ci_sessions' table is not created.

For eg: in ruby on rails, once we have code, we can do

```
rake db:migrate
```

which will create all tables. I want this feature.

In Django, we can do

```
 python manage.py syncdb
```

which will create all tables.

In java, I will have an sql file, I will execute that file using db commands which will generate db table.

Anything like any of the above in codeigniter ?

Answer (score 1):

if the CI project is fully completed, you can export your database and import it on the server you will be using... about creating database or table thru php code you can check [CI DB Forge Documentation](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/forge.html) or [check this one](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html)

Comment: I dont have access to the db. I think the links you gave are useful during development of code. Since we have code, cant I execute single command that creates the db skeleton? For eg: in ruby on rails, once we have code, we can do rake db:migrate which will create all tables. I want this feature.

Answer (score 0):

in config.php file you need to change sess_use_database false or create table name ci_session

```
$config['sess_use_database']    = FALSE;
$config['sess_table_name']      = 'ci_session';
```

Comment: Hi, thats working, but please tell me if I am correct - the only way to create db/tables is to generate .sql file from the old db or directly dump from old db. No other way, right ?(like syncdb in python/Django).

Answer (score 0):

That depends. When I was using Doctrine (an ORM layer for PHP/MySQL) with CodeIgniter I had to use a call on the URL to generate DB models. It generated models maps to all the tables in the database.